# No session repository could be auto-configured, check your configuration (session store type is 'null')

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-boot, repository

What does this spring boot start up error mean?

```
2016-07-04 21:53:53 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionAutoConfiguration$SessionRepositoryValidator': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No session repository could be auto-configured, check your configuration (session store type is 'null')
```

Comment: i'm wonder why intllij project by default couse this issue, and anopther (said tomcat is provided in dependecies) BTW my issues fixed for now

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You have Spring Session on your classpath and no store was provided. We can't take that decision for you as if your classpath changes, the store type may change according to our preferences and you'd lose them without any sort of warning.

Historically we only supported redis so if you have that we'll use it transparently. Please set `spring.session.store-type` to the store you want to use for Spring Session. If Spring Session is on your classpath and you don't want to use it right now, set `spring.session.store-type=none`

**Update**: given the number of upvotes, this looks like a confusing error message so I've opened [#9284](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9284) to improve it.

Comment: Got it. This is a modification to the way that spring sessions originally operated. [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5838). Applying your advise works.

Comment: Just an addition: Set this property in your application.properties.

Comment: Why? You can set that property anywhere where boot is looking. It could be a command-line switch, a system property or whatever else. I agree that you probably want to put it there in this case though.

Comment: what is a store type? is it a name of DB we gonna use? for example i have to tell it if i use embeded hsqldb, or postgres, or as redis(i think i saw it's name in nosql db list) or etc? and any thing it is, how we do that?

Comment: Thank you. Or set it to jdbc as per http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-session.html if the database is configured and ready.